# How to control terminal by NSTask?

Tags: pipe, nstask

My source code is below:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    char str[80];
    memset(str, 0x00, 80);
    sprintf(str, "%s %s", "open -a","terminal.app");
    NSString *cmdstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

    NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", cmdstr, nil]];

    NSPipe *pipe_out = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe_out];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data = [[pipe_out fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];

    [task waitUntilExit];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);

}
```

and here are the questions:

1. I opened "Terminal Application", my goal is making communication between terminal application and main API through Pipe or somethings. How can I make pipe or something between terminal app and main API?
2. When the terminal application was opened, I couldn't open new terminal application. How can I open terminal application at new tab or new window?

Answer (score 0):

For 2. you'll need to figure out how to use [ScriptingBridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)